# Android Firebase Auth UI: startActivityforResult Invalid Method Declaration, Return Type Required

Tags: java, android, firebase, android-studio, firebase-authentication

I am trying to integrate the FireBase Auth UI into my Android app and I am following the Firebase tutorial for setting up authentication. When I am using

```
package com.example.kishan.basicproject;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import com.firebase.ui.auth.AuthUI;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}

private static final int RC_SIGN_IN = 123;
```

// ...

```
// Choose authentication providers
List<AuthUI.IdpConfig> providers = Arrays.asList(
        new AuthUI.IdpConfig.EmailBuilder().build(),
        new AuthUI.IdpConfig.PhoneBuilder().build(),
        new AuthUI.IdpConfig.GoogleBuilder().build(),
        new AuthUI.IdpConfig.FacebookBuilder().build(),
        new AuthUI.IdpConfig.TwitterBuilder().build());

// Create and launch sign-in intent

startActivityForResult(
        AuthUI.getInstance()
    .createSignInIntentBuilder()
    .setAvailableProviders(providers)
    .build(),
RC_SIGN_IN);
```

}

The error I get in Android Studio is "cannot resolve getInstance()" or "invalid method declaration; return type required". I have searched on Firebase forums, but have not found help. I was wondering if someone could point me in the correct direction? Thank you for all your help!!

Answer (score 0):

this happens to my once and what i did was to include the startActivityForResult() inside the onCreate() method, something like this:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    startActivityForResult(AuthUI.getInstance()
    .createSignInIntentBuilder()
    .setAvailableProviders(providers)
    .build(),
            RC_SIGN_IN);
}
```

I followed up this and works https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/firebaseui